# Sqlite query with jaydata functions simultaneously

Tags: sqlite, jaydata

I am using offlineDB as Jaydata+Sqlite.
I have created database,tables,fields and inserted the data too using Jaydata functions.
Now I want that for some functionality I want to run sqlite queries for the same database tables.

```
Is it possible to do the same?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. JayData isn't black magic, it provides a unified JavaScript API for all storage technologies. The API translates the JavaScript API to SQLite queries. If you don't modify the database schema in your native SQLite queries (so you use only CRUD your records) and don't want to run native queries and JayData operations at the same time, everything will work fine.

Comment: I do not understand "don't want to run native queries and JayData operations at the same time".
Sir,I want to use Jaydata functions for selection query and sqlite queries for grouping data.So,can I write both the things in a single file?

Comment: sure, you can do this. I only meant that pay attention to concurrency